# how to fix heroku error while deploying an expressjs app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I've been trying to fix a heroku api but I keep getting an error which I cant fix. The app is not even running, it goes straight to the error. It was working until I recently made an update to the api.
The error is shown as

```
    2019-10-18T21:40:06.936984+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load 
    (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    2019-10-18T21:40:06.936986+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require 
    (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
     2019-10-18T21:40:06.936988+00:00 app[web.1]: at require 
     (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    2019-10-18T21:40:06.936989+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/routes/api.js:7:16)
    2019-10-18T21:40:06.936991+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile 
    (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    2019-10-18T21:40:06.944691+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

    2019-10-18T21:40:06.945081+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
    2019-10-18T21:40:06.946204+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! quickJobs-api@1.0.0 start: `node 
    server.js`
2019-10-18T21:40:06.946319+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-10-18T21:40:06.946542+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-10-18T21:40:06.946663+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the quickJobs-api@1.0.0 start script.
2019-10-18T21:40:06.946779+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-10-18T21:40:06.953214+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-10-18T21:40:06.953367+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-10-18T21:40:06.953452+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-10-18T21_40_06_948Z-debug.log
2019-10-18T21:40:07.008783+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-10-18T21:40:24.571093+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-10-18T22:05:16.977483+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=quickjobsapi.herokuapp.com request_id=a50a5c3e-7152-4ce1-942f-df572188531b fwd="63.143.196.162" dyno= connect= serv
ice= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-10-18T22:05:17.639126+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=quickjobsapi.herokuapp.com request_id=405f9fd7-ae38-478e-b182-7e5306ab0fa6 fwd="63.143.196.162" dyno= co
nnect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-10-18T22:05:48.086732+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-10-18T22:05:50.688489+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-10-18T22:05:53.119843+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-10-18T22:05:53.119869+00:00 app[web.1]: > quickJobs-api@1.0.0 start /app
2019-10-18T22:05:53.119871+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2019-10-18T22:05:53.119872+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-10-18T22:05:54.001916+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-10-18T22:05:53.873724+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:807
2019-10-18T22:05:53.873754+00:00 app[web.1]: return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
2019-10-18T22:05:53.873756+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-10-18T22:05:53.873758+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-10-18T22:05:53.873760+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: /app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header
2019-10-18T22:05:53.873761+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:807:18)
2019-10-18T22:05:53.873763+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
2019-10-18T22:05:53.873765+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
2019-10-18T22:05:53.873767+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
2019-10-18T22:05:53.873768+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
2019-10-18T22:05:53.873770+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
2019-10-18T22:05:53.873771+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
2019-10-18T22:05:53.873773+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
2019-10-18T22:05:53.882321+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-10-18T22:05:53.882732+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-10-18T22:05:53.883970+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! quickJobs-api@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2019-10-18T22:05:53.884082+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-10-18T22:05:53.884277+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-10-18T22:05:53.884398+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the quickJobs-api@1.0.0 start script.
2019-10-18T22:05:53.884514+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-10-18T22:05:53.914312+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-10-18T22:05:53.914489+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-10-18T22:05:53.914584+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-10-18T22_05_53_885Z-debug.log
2019-10-18T22:05:54.019964+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-10-18T22:05:53.977749+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-10-18T22:05:57.322980+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-10-18T22:06:00.008642+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-10-18T22:06:00.008674+00:00 app[web.1]: > quickJobs-api@1.0.0 start /app

2019-10-18T22:06:00.008676+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2019-10-18T22:06:00.008678+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-10-18T22:06:00.907169+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:807
2019-10-18T22:06:00.907208+00:00 app[web.1]: return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
2019-10-18T22:06:00.907211+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-10-18T22:06:00.907214+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-10-18T22:06:00.907216+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: /app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header
2019-10-18T22:06:00.907218+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:807:18)
2019-10-18T22:06:00.907220+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
2019-10-18T22:06:00.907223+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
2019-10-18T22:06:00.907225+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
2019-10-18T22:06:00.907228+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
2019-10-18T22:06:00.907229+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
2019-10-18T22:06:00.907232+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
2019-10-18T22:06:00.907234+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
2019-10-18T22:06:00.907235+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
2019-10-18T22:06:00.907238+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
2019-10-18T22:06:00.907242+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
2019-10-18T22:06:00.907244+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
2019-10-18T22:06:00.907247+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
2019-10-18T22:06:00.907249+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
2019-10-18T22:06:00.907251+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/routes/api.js:7:16)
2019-10-18T22:06:00.907253+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
2019-10-18T22:06:00.925298+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-10-18T22:06:00.925759+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-10-18T22:06:00.926956+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! quickJobs-api@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2019-10-18T22:06:00.927125+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-10-18T22:06:00.927387+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-10-18T22:06:00.927644+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the quickJobs-api@1.0.0 start script.
2019-10-18T22:06:00.927832+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-10-18T22:06:00.942491+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-10-18T22:06:00.942496+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-10-18T22:06:00.942498+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-10-18T22_06_00_929Z-debug.log
2019-10-18T22:06:01.013650+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-10-18T22:06:00.991627+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
Git
2019-10-18T22:06:00.778487+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-10-18T22:06:01.574620+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=quickjobsapi.herokuapp.com request_id=e500ac9e-cc2f-4cde-9f91-8424f36c57f2 fwd="63.143.196.162" dyno= connect= serv
ice= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-10-18T22:06:02.282334+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=quickjobsapi.herokuapp.com request_id=38013505-dfbc-4e8a-90e4-e55077f9b467 fwd="63.143.196.162" dyno= co
nnect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

My server.js file has

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()
app.use(cors())
//const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000,function(){
 console.log('server has been started')
})

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "500mb"}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "500mb", extended: true, parameterLimit:50000}));
app.use('/api',require('./routes/api'))
```

The other files are just the api and the schema for mongodb.
Please help

Comment: What "update" did you make to your app?

Comment: Remove the routes, and try again. If it fails: It's in the new routes, somewhere that's causing your app to crash.

Comment: did you test the app locally before you deployed it ?!

Comment: yes it runs locally

Comment: @FramkerZ I did tht and I still get the same erroe

Comment: can you show us what `/routes/api` contains ?

Comment: do you deploy `node_modules` with your server files?

Comment: the entire file gets deplyed

Answer (score 2):

I see that there is a bcrypt related error. Are you using different Node.js version on your local dev and your prod? If yes then try to ignore the package manager lock file `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json`.

lock file usually "hold" version specific dependency, in some case package with native dependency like bcrypt can cause some issue.